# Architecture of a modern web-app with a lot of pages

Tags: web-applications, architecture

I'm trying to choose the architecture for the web-app with a lot of non-static pages (more than 50 pages with different content).
The major part of pages has the same scheme (menu + right menu + content zone + bottom).
The content also can be very different (tables, text, images or content for user interaction)
But there are pages which absolutely different.

How does it work now? I have the server with Perl (yeah, it's a very old app) where I generate pages (html + js + css) and then just send it to the user. The data on the page depends on every user.

I have some experience with SPA (React + TypeScript) but I understand that SPA does not suitable for my case.

Can you please recommend something to read or just tell me the name of the modern solution for my case?

Also I need help with technologies. As for me, Typescript with webpack and babel are the best for the client side, but again I don't know how it should work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - comments as 'answer'.  To answer this properly, we (well, me, anyway) will need more info:

- What are your technology constraints?  You mention Perl, is that the current state? Can you get off that or not?

In term of the solution, a data-driven web-site like this is pretty common.  A stack like ASP.Net (which I only mention because it's what I am most familiar with) will do this easily - and there are other stacks that will have comparable features:

Look up "data driven web sites", perhaps.

What you want is (warning - random list):

- A technology stack that in known for building data driven web sites, i.e. can implement the three essential logical layers: UI, logic, data access.
- The data access code has access to some useful database solution to store data - you mentioned users seeing different data, so no doubt you'll need a database - again, pick one that works for the stack you choose, and that is popular (easy to get help).
- The main part of the stack is the web application and the developer tools that support it.  Together these should let you easily create the "view" pages with structure, reusable components (e.g. navigation, widgets), styles, client side scripts, etc.  They should also let you easily program the dynamic parts of the logic behind them, the "controllers".
- The code / language / technology used to build the dynamic parts of the pages should also allow you to build the other layers I mentioned above.  Object Orientated OO languages can be a good fit for that.  Pick one that is strongly typed so that you get good design-time, compile-time and runtime support for debugging.
- Good web app stacks and IDE's will also provide strong reusability features though creating 'template' pages so you get consistency when you want it, and the ability to create reusable controls (that have UI and logic).
- If you use OO, do some reading on good OO design principles (e.g. [this](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/%7Ecs3443/notes/designPrinciples/designPrinciples.html), [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) and [this](https://hackernoon.com/10-oop-design-principles-every-programmer-should-know-f187436caf65)).  Do expect to learn it all at once, but what you can apply will help you in the long run.
- Client-side scripting is important to a lot of people these days - for good reason, so when choosing a toolset and architecture think about how much client-side scripting you need / want to do.

Note: **Views** and **Controllers** come from MVC, which is one type of architecture often used by wep app builders, but there are others.

- Lastly, to provide data on a per-user basis you'll need to handle user authentication and authorization; most decent web app stacks will provide assistance in that through some combination of add-ons, libraries, design patterns, reference architectures, guidance for implementing standards like OAuth, providers to integrate with popular identity providers (so you can do "social" log in off Google, etc).

**Reading List**

If you're totally new to building web apps, here's some reading material.  I have just done a search and selected articles that, at a glance, look like they might be useful (and have the least pop-ups).

- https://litslink.com/blog/web-application-architecture
- https://mobidev.biz/blog/web-application-architecture-types
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures
- https://www.intuz.com/guide-on-web-app-architecture

**Update - ASP.Net as Example of View & Controller Dynamic Page**

In response to your comment, especially

> How to build pages, on which side

I don't know anything about using Kotlin and typescript together (I can have a look), but if you think it might work try doing a proof of concept  like a "hello world" simple site to prove the technology and your intended architecture.  If you aren't familiar with it, check out the concept of a [Steel Thread](https://simplicable.com/new/steel-thread).

In terms of how to build dynamic pages, in stacks like ASP.Net, Pages and WebControls have two pieces that work together: one (the View) is what looks like an HTML page, but which can also include mark-up that the ASP engine recognizes:

```
<%@ Page Title="My Page" Language="C#" 
  MasterPageFile="~/Desktop.Master" 
  CodeBehind="RandomPage.aspx.cs" %>

  <h1>Welcome to my page</h1>

  <asp:TextBox ID="txtMyText" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

  ...
```

In this part you can mix all the usual client side mark-up, style and script code.  You see it has `Desktop.Master` which is a template which provides a degree of overall consistency.  The view works hand-in-hand with what ASP.Net calls the code-behind page (the Controller) which in this case is `RandomPage.aspx.cs`, e.g.:

```
namespace Adrian.RandomWebsites.Alpha
{
    public partial class RandomPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtMyText.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

This is where you can do backend processing, calling databases and populating the page/webcontrols with data.  Here I'm setting the TextBox to output the date/time to the page.

`RandomPage` is a class, written in C# which is an OO language, so you get the full deal with inheritance, polymorphism, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
About the current stack. I'm using Perl + vanila JS (as I said it's a very old project). and yes, I want to change both. 
Honestly, I like Kotlin for the server side and TypeScript for the client side. But maybe you know better languages?

One of the main problems is how to rewrite client and server side.
How to build pages, on which side.
For example, now I have a lot of pages with the same construction but different content. Maybe I can build this structure on the client side and just put inside it the content which I get from the server.